# Group visibility of rich:columns inside rich:datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces

I have a set of columns inside a rich:datatable, those columns are visible based on some preprocessed conditions. An example of what I want to do is this:

```
<rich:datatable value="tableList" var="list">

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{condition}">
        <rich:column>
            Component
        <rich:column>

        <rich:column>
            Component
        <rich:column>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not condition}">
        <rich:column>
            Component
        </rich:column>
    </h:panelGroup>

</rich:datatable>
```

The problem here is that the panelGroup tag never gets rendered inside the rich:datatable, even when I remove the "rendered" condition. I tried with an a4j:outputPanel and a few others but none worked.

I could remove the panel and put the condition in each column but that would be the last thing I would do.

Why is not working? Regards.

Comment: Apart form the `datatable` -> `dataTable` red herring, the syntax looks fine. Sure that you have the panelgroup inside the column in your real code as well?

Comment: My bad, there was so many code in the table that I mistook the error. The panelGroup that fails to show are the ones that contains the column, not he other way around, I´ll edit the code to reflect the problem.

Comment: Well, that explains the problem. The panelgroup cannot be a direct child of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I am pretty sure that the `<rich:dataTable>` will ignore any direct children that are not a `UIColumn` or `Column` object (I just had a look on `org.richfaces.component.ColumnsIterator`, used by `UIDataTable`).

In others words, your `<h:panelGroup>` will simply be ignored by the `<rich:dataTable>`, not matter when the `rendered` attribute value is.

To solve your problem, I see three solutions:

1. Put a `rendered` attribute on each `<rich:column>`;
2. Use the [`<rich:columnGroup>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columnGroup.html) component;
3. Define two `<rich:dataTable>`, one display when `#{condition}` is evaluated to `true`, the other one when it is `false`.

Comment: 1) and 3) would be a nightmare in my particular case, especially 3) since there is a list of fixed columns inside the datatable and the amount of duplicate code would be just too much.

I already worked with columGroup but no mater what I do, it prints a <tr> and the contents gets moved to the next row, even inside another column.